# Jquery draggable and overflow scroll

Tags: jquery

I am just wondering if its possible to actually get overflow scroll to work in conjunction with Jquery UI draggable on a mobile phone. I know Jquery UI does not work on mobile but I have got a script that hacks it so it not only reacts to mouse but also touch.

right now if I drop in a code to get Jquery UI draggable to work then the overflow scroll will not so yeah I am just wondering if anyone knows how to get around that?

here is my code

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html >
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no, width=100%" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://webprofolio.freeserver.me/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
<style>

#parent
{
    background-color:blue;
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
}

#content
{
    background-color:red;
    width:380px;
    height:380px;
    overflow-y:auto;
    margin:auto;
}

#thebody
{
    background-color:green;
    width:600px;
    height:400px;
}  

</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="thebody">
<div id="parent">
<div id="content">
<p>
Hello gentlemen welcome to the end of the days!!! you want to buy some sandwiches? No thanks, I don't like strawberries
Hello gentlemen welcome to the end of the days!!! you want to buy some sandwiches? No thanks, I don't like strawberries
Hello gentlemen welcome to the end of the days!!! you want to buy some sandwiches? No thanks, I don't like strawberries
Hello gentlemen welcome to the end of the days!!! you want to buy some sandwiches? No thanks, I don't like strawberries
Hello gentlemen welcome to the end of the days!!! you want to buy some sandwiches? No thanks, I don't like strawberries
Hello gentlemen welcome to the end of the days!!! you want to buy some sandwiches? No thanks, I don't like strawberries
Hello gentlemen welcome to the end of the days!!! you want to buy some sandwiches? No thanks, I don't like strawberries
Hello gentlemen welcome to the end of the days!!! you want to buy some sandwiches? No thanks, I don't like strawberries
Hello gentlemen welcome to the end of the days!!! you want to buy some sandwiches? No thanks, I don't like strawberries
Hello gentlemen welcome to the end of the days!!! you want to buy some sandwiches? No thanks, I don't like strawberries
Hello gentlemen welcome to the end of the days!!! you want to buy some sandwiches? No thanks, I don't like strawberries
Hello gentlemen welcome to the end of the days!!! you want to buy some sandwiches? No thanks, I don't like strawberries
Hello gentlemen welcome to the end of the days!!! you want to buy some sandwiches? No thanks, I don't like strawberries
Hello gentlemen welcome to the end of the days!!! you want to buy some sandwiches? No thanks, I don't like strawberries
Hello gentlemen welcome to the end of the days!!! you want to buy some sandwiches? No thanks, I don't like strawberries
Hello gentlemen welcome to the end of the days!!! you want to buy some sandwiches? No thanks, I don't like strawberries
Hello gentlemen welcome to the end of the days!!! you want to buy some sandwiches? No thanks, I don't like strawberries
Hello gentlemen welcome to the end of the days!!! you want to buy some sandwiches? No thanks, I don't like strawberries
Hello gentlemen welcome to the end of the days!!! you want to buy some sandwiches? No thanks, I don't like strawberries
Hello gentlemen welcome to the end of the days!!! you want to buy some sandwiches? No thanks, I don't like strawberries
Hello gentlemen welcome to the end of the days!!! you want to buy some sandwiches? No thanks, I don't like strawberries
The last paragraph
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script>

touchMove();

function touchMove()
{
    $( "#parent" ).draggable({ axis: "x" , containment:"parent"},
    {});

}



</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you _have_ to be so offensive in your original post? Good thing I edited it...

Comment: Please don't use offensive language here. Stack Overflow is a site for professionals.

Comment: oh i am really sorry I just copied and paste random things i didn't meant to be offensive by bad for not checking before putting it on

Comment: Anyway I solved it by going into the Jquery file and took out g.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

You are missing closing tag ">"

```
<script src="http://webprofolio.freeserver.me/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"</script>
```

To

```
<script src="http://webprofolio.freeserver.me/jquery.ui.touch-punch.min.js"></script>
```

Now it works fine.

Comment: Hi Ved, I had to before but I reedited and missed the closing tag. I guess i didn't make the question clear enough :p I know the dragging is working fine. What I wanted is the overflow scroll ( The contents inside the div. these "Hello gentlemen welcome to the end of the days!!! you want to buy some sandwiches? No thanks, I don't like strawberries") I should be able to scroll them down and see "The last paragraph" sentence eventually

NOTE: it works on computer browser but I want to make it work on mobile device. it has something to do with the draggable function in Jquery UI